# Gradient background is cutting off a png image

Tags: html, css

I am not able to make a shadow gradient background for one image described in the following snippet. I have tried various solutions but couldn't make it to work. The image gets cut off from bottom.

```css
.circle {      
  line-height: 0.33;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 20px #adadad;
}
```

```html
<img class="circle" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kEf0.png">
```

Comment: Can you consider wrapping the image in a DIV as answered by @Viral in below answer?

Comment: Shadow property works for the div that is why it is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out the below solution. I hope this helps.

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0.33;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 20px #adadad;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"> 
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kEf0.png">  
</div>
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on your problem, i'm not sure what you wanted it to look like but this solution doesn't make the "x2" appear outside.

You need to wrap your image in a div bigger than the image if you want a circle border to contain the whole image. Adding border-radius basically makes a square border smaller, therefore covering your image.

```css
.circle-border {
  text-align: center;
  width: 450px;
  height: 430px;
  line-height: 0.33;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 20px #adadad;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-border">
  <img class="circle" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kEf0.png">  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.circle-border {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0.33;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 20px #adadad;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-border">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kEf0.png">  
</div>
```